# How do I install dataset on python not using pip or easy_install?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to install data set on Ubuntu and when I use

```
pip install dataset
```

it gives me a long error message, and from what I could debug from it is that permission to the directory is denied. When I try

```
easy_install dataset
```

it says `error: can't create or remove files in install directory because permission is denied` Maybe my account doesn't have write access to this directory?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pip install dataset` or `sudo easy_install dataset`?

Comment: I haven't but now that  I did it worked, so thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're receiving the error `can't create or remove in install directory because permission is denied` then you need to run your commands with `sudo` privileges

Try:

```
sudo pip install dataset
```

or

```
sudo easy_install dataset
```

Comment: yeah that actually worked, I didn't realize sudo meant giving the permission

Comment: @AbdullahBaraka it gives administrator privileges for the command you're running